# iOS - Google Analytics - Visitor Loyalty

Tags: ios, google-analytics

the Visitor Loyalty numbers for the iOS Google Analytics seem to be wrong (at least in my case). According the numbers the app is visited only 1 or 2 times. Never more than 2. This made no sense to me so I created a new account using Google's example app, same results.

Now the question remains: is this a known issue, do you guys also have problems with Visitor Loyalty numbers with the use of the iOS GA sdk or am I missing something here? Are the cookies overwritten or deleted after the second time? All the other results are okay (also the absolute unique visitors) so the cookies don't seem to be the problem..

(btw with the Android sdk I don't have these problems)

Comment: Hi, Did you find any solution to this issue? I'm having exactly the same problem.

Comment: Still the same issue here. Did somebody fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Google [say](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33087):

> Unique Visitors represents the number of unduplicated (counted only once) visitors to your website over the course of a specified time period. A Unique Visitor is determined using cookies.

So every time you re-install your app on device or simulator, a new unique visitor will be detected.